# Windows to go usb 3.0 booting problems

Tags: usb-3, windows-to-go

why Windows to go don't boot from USB 3.0 in **some** PC? It start booting, but after few minutes shows blue screen with error: "Inaccessible Boot Device". On USB 2.0 works good.
P.S. I use Kingston DataTraveler Workspace, which is certificated for Windows to go.

Comment: It's probably a lack of the required USB3.0 driver for the computer you're plugging it into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most USB 3.0 ports have been implemented using descrete logic, that is not built into the chipset. This means that this port is not fully configured until after Boot. Thus this port is not available durring BIOS Boot. Newer notebooks will take care of this. You might also want to make sure you have your latest bios, just in case it was enabled after ship. Weird that it started booting...

Comment: So, how to know is boot from USB 3.0 is possible when you are planing to buy new PC?

Comment: can you give a link to "discrete logic" that includes why you think that means it will behave this way?