# Windows To Go boot error 0xC00000E9 on USB 3.0 ports

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, windows-to-go

I found a post ([Windows to go usb 3.0 booting problems](https://superuser.com/questions/571125/windows-to-go-usb-3-0-booting-problems)) which may be the answer but I wanted to throw this out there because the scenario described is not exactly the same and the error code is not mentioned there.

When I use USB 2.0 ports my IronKey device boots fine (albeit slowly). When I use either of the two USB 3.0 ports on the back of my computer I get a bluescreen and the error code 0xc00000e9. Research shows that Windows believes there is a problem with the OS's files but I believe this is incorrect because, again, it boots without a problem on USB 2.0.

Is the post I found earlier accurate for my case too or is there something else happening?

Comment: 0xc00000e9 = STATUS_UNEXPECTED_IO_ERROR. Which USb 3.0 chipset do you use?