# Windows 8.1 To Go inaccessible boot device error

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, windows-to-go

I have a Windows 8 partition on my hard drive which I've been trying to get to boot into Windows.

I first just boot into my drive, then I get a screen saying:

> :(
>
> Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart.
> We're just collecting som error info, and then we'll restart for you.

And then under this it says for literally a few milliseconds (had to film the screen to capture the message):

> If you'd like to more more, you can search later online for this error:
> INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Then it tries to boot once or twice more and a screen shows with the error code `0xc0000001`.

I am able to start into Safe Mode, and I have tried `sfc /scannow` (both from the External Drive and the Installation CD, it couldn't open repair tool), automatic reparation (both from the External Drive and the Installation CD, it either couldn't find or repair my computer, sometimes `8007001f` error), a half reset/file refresh (I was warned this is not possible on Windows To Go, so I did it through the CD, then it said that the device that Windows is installed on is locked) and `chkdsk /f`.

I have tried a few other minor things (like `bootrec /rebuildbcd`) but these are the main things, is there anyone here who know what I can do?

PC: Macbook Pro (Retina, 15 inch, Early 2013).

Comment: So where does `WIndows To Go` which is a feature of Windows 8 Enterprise come into play?  WinRE isn't `Windows to Go` which is what you were actually in.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what WinRE is, but Windows To Go comes into play because I am able to run this exact copy on an internal drive, but not on an External Drive.

Comment: Check this troubleshooting article this might help you ; http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm

Comment: Maybe this issue is the same: http://superuser.com/questions/571125/windows-to-go-usb-3-0-booting-problems

Comment: Some early implementations of USB 3.0 and motherboards prevented booting from 3.0, a reason manufacturers leave at least one legacy 2.0 port to run their recovery discs from.

Comment: @Moab not on mine, I only have to USB 3 ports.

Comment: @DisplayName, consider putting the make and model of the PC in your question.

Comment: I still don’t entirely get it. Is this a Windows To Go installation we’re talking about? Or is it a regular Windows installation?

Comment: @Daniel B I installed it as usual, I think it is a Windows To Go, because when I boot up (safe mode only works as I said above) it tells something like "taking out the USB could crash your Windows To Go environment"

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the information you gave suggests you actually have Windows To Go. You may have misread a generic error message.

Desktop installations of Windows do not support booting from USB storage devices. They only work on internal hard disks as well as some eSATA hard disks, because they appear to the system the same way like internal disks.

Comment: Well, everytime I boot into Safe Mode it says something about Windows To Go.

Comment: @DisplayName - Did you figure out what to do?

Comment: @AlexS No, I just think that my USB drive is incompatible with Windows To Go.