# Reinstalling Windows - boot from USB not detected

Tags: windows, boot, usb, operating-systems

I bought a notebook without any OS. I installed Windows 10 using the [Microsoft download tool](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10) and a USB drive. Right now, I have `Windows 10 S` installed on it. I then bought `Windows 10 Home` and since its product key cannot be used for `Windows 10 S`, I have to install Windows again.

My problem is that the Microsoft USB provided with Windows 10 does not seem to be detected in the `boot menu`.

[As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6BQu.jpg):
[image]

it only shows:

- `[Windows Boot Manager (PO: Crucial_CT275MX300SSD4)]`
- `[UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller]`

I cannot find `legacy support` option either in the section `advanced`, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxtbC.jpg):
[image]

I am not sure how to proceed. Should I hit [Boot Override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCtJH.jpg)?
[image]

**Update**

When plugging the USB into my desktop PC it indeed seems to be recognized, [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RfGT.jpg).
[image]
 And about the `UEFI`:

- when executing `start -> run -> MSInfo32` I have the following `BIOS Mode: UEFI`
- and in the `boot` menu I have `UEFI Boot [Enabled]`

Comment: Well written question! I would suggest trying the boot stick in another computer, and seeing if the boot menu sees it. Also check if UEFI is enabled, as it is likely turned off. See: https://superuser.com/questions/1008125/when-uefi-motherboard-firmware-is-set-to-uefinot-legacy-usb-is-not-detecte

Comment: @studiohack I updated my question, I hope that helps.

Comment: use Rufus to create **GPT** version (not MBR) of the flash drive from the Windows 10 ISO

Comment: @magicandre1981 alright I will give that a try. Is there a way to tell 
whether the Windows10 USB is GPT/MBR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles across the same issue, here is how the problem got solved.

1. The notebook (pictures 1 and 2) with the underlying issue had a graphic card related issue. So I exchanged it for another one (still *XMG*, different model). Now the brand new notebook (no OS installed) did **not** recognize the *Microsoft Windows* USB drive. It did however recognize my flash drive with *Windows 10* on it (created via Media Creation Tool), much like the first notebook did.
2. As can be seen in picture 3, my desktop PC did recognize the *Microsoft Windows* USB drive.

This led me to believe that the problem lies in the combination *Schenker XMG* notebook and *Microsoft Windows* USB drive.

In the end, to install *Windows 10 Home*, all I had to do was to enter my product key during the installation of *Windows* (i.e. it is not needed to use the USB attached with the license).

Answer (score 0):

Use Mini tool partition wizard to look at the partition table on the key, it will tell you wethere it's GPT or MBR.